# No internet connection with MAC os DHCP with manual address

Tags: macos, dhcp, ipv4

I want to configure remote management on my macbook pro (2017, 13 inch no touchbar). 
I go to system preferences -> network->advanced (for my LAN ethernet connection) -> Configure IPv4 (leave IPv6 at automatically) and then change IPv4 to Router default 192.168.251.1 with .111 at end instead of .1. I have tried several different values for IPv4 address and after applying each of these changes I lose my network connection. Is there a work around ?

Comment: What happens if you set the address to the same one that was previously automatically assigned? BTW, to do this properly you will also need to set a fixed address at the router, based on the Mac's NIC MAC address... though normally, that's all that should be needed. Fix it at the router, leave the Mac alone.

Comment: @user196711 - Instead of submitting several comments providing helpful information.  You should provide the information as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience routers don't normally define static IPs but they do have a net mask which will limit the range of IPs available. Normally the minimum range will be 16 with the router within the first two and broadcast at the last one. If we assume the router's address is 192.168.251.1 then I would try to set something between 192.168.251.5 and 192.168.251.14 unless you have further information about the router's settings. I also set everything to IPv4 - faster and more reliable - probably for at least the next ten years. You may find this page helpful: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/